# PHP - date scheduling

Tags: php, date, input, timer

hello is there way to locked a page based on the input date. Like for example admins input june 18 , 2018 starttime to june 22, 2018 endtime . some users function is blocked or disabled until the starttime and be disabled again on the endtime.  unfortunately i can't post a code because i dont know how to do it. any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hello once solution is you need to change it in php.ini and disabled_function but that make not sense for user defined function and also can't change at run-time so i would like to prefer you alternate solution is

```
<?php
    $startTime   = strtotime('2008-09-22');
    $endTime     = strtotime('2008-09-25');
    $now = new DateTime();
    $currentDate = $now->format('Y-m-d');
    $currentTime = $now->getTimestamp(); 

    function a(){
     if($currentTime>$startTime && $currentTime<$endTime){
       // in this scope this is enable so you can put logic here
     } else {
       // in this scope this is disable section so you can return error warning and false
        return false;
     }
    }
?>
```

Comment: in the disable part can i disable the page in there? im sorry i cant understand any of this im just a begineer

Comment: Yes you can write there javascript code and by identifier like $("#div").disable() based on your logic

Comment: sir its me again could you gave me an example code how to disable a div or page?